# ¿Cómo puedo desactivar los console.log en todo el proyecto de TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

Tengo un proyecto realizado con TypeScript y soportada por SAM. ¿Hay alguna forma profesional de "apagar" todos los `console.log()` que tengo dentro del código?

Actualmente, tengo esta línea de código por cada archivo que contenga `console.log()`

```javascript
if (process.env.ENABLE_CONSOLE === 'false') console.log = () => {};
```

Comment: Que tiene de malo manera??

Comment: Hola niko, ¿quieres es deshacerte de todos los console.log()? ¿estas usando VSCODE como editor?

Comment: Yo sugiero `console.log = () => {}`. Básicamente cambia console.log por una función que no hace nada.

Comment: Aquí está la misma pregunta en SO en ingles, quizás te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code

Comment: @Yussef que tengo que hacerlo en cada archivo .ts por separado

Comment: @Candelo no deshacerme, porque se necesitan en caso de debug, pero si apagarlos cuando se desplieguen las aplicaciones.

Comment: @AndresGardiol Voy a darle una mirada, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particularmente, desaconsejo alterar de una u otra forma los tipos o funciones incorporadas en cualquier lenguaje de programación que lo permita, como JavaScript o TypeScript.

Puede que desees inhabilitar la instrucción `console.log` para tu código. Esto puede conseguirse sobre escribiendo dicha función de esta forma:

```js
window.console.log   = () => {};
window.console.warn  = () => {};
window.console.info  = () => {};
window.console.error = () => {};

console.log   ('Log');
console.warn  ('Warn');
console.info  ('Info');
console.error ('Error');
```

<sup>Tal como sugiere la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73435317/9443618) de [Lukas Liesis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1737158/lukas-liesis), el [comentario de Mateo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/582256/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-desactivar-los-console-log-en-todo-el-proyecto-de-typescript#comment1029778_582256) y [el comentario de Andres Gardiol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/582256/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-desactivar-los-console-log-en-todo-el-proyecto-de-typescript#comment1029791_582256)</sup>

En teoría esto soluciona tu problema, ya que `window.console` accede al objeto global de consola. El problema con esto es que estás inutilizando la consola para todos, esto incluye cualquier librería o módulo que estés utilizando.

- ¿Dónde se mostrarán los mensajes de estas utilidades de terceros?
- ¿Consideraste que esto traerá conflicto con las antes mencionadas utilidades?

---

[Este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/582256/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-desactivar-los-console-log-en-todo-el-proyecto-de-typescript#comment1029800_582277) sugiere emplear un objeto envolvente alrededor de `console.log` y resulta una mejor opción que tu apuesta original.

Recuerda, altera solo los tipos y funciones que creaste vos.

Te sugiero crear tu propia utilidad para la consola, como por ejemplo esta:

```js
class Logger
{
    static enabled = true;

    static log()
    {
        if (Logger.enabled)
        {
            console.log(...arguments);
        }
    }
    
    static warn()
    {
        if (Logger.enabled)
        {
            console.warn(...arguments);
        }
    }
    
    static info()
    {
        if (Logger.enabled)
        {
            console.info(...arguments);
        }
    }
    
    static error()
    {
        if (Logger.enabled)
        {
            console.error(...arguments);
        }
    }
}

console.log('Logger encendido');

Logger.enabled = true;
Logger.log   ('Hola', 'Mundo');
Logger.warn  ('Hola', 'Mundo');
Logger.info  ('Hola', 'Mundo');
Logger.error ('Hola', 'Mundo');

console.log('Logger apagado');

Logger.enabled = false;
Logger.log   ('Hola', 'Mundo');
Logger.warn  ('Hola', 'Mundo');
Logger.info  ('Hola', 'Mundo');
Logger.error ('Hola', 'Mundo');
```

Entonces reemplazas `console.log` por `Logger.log` donde necesites encender/apagar el flujo de salida y estableces `Logger.enabled` en `true` o `false` una sola vez al inicio de tu proyecto.

Ejemplo:

```
// ENABLE_CONSOLE parece ser una cadena, no un booleano
Logger.enabled = process.env.ENABLE_CONSOLE === 'false';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Héctor, esta muy completa y creo que la primera opción me sirve mucho. De mi parte, no tengo problemas con que las consolas de los terceros se apague, pero hay algún riesgo que deba saber al respecto?

Comment: @nikolo520 De mi parte, si no tienes problemas con inhibirte de los mensajes de terceros, entiendo que fuera de mi respuesta no tengo más riesgos que mencionarte

Answer (score 0):

No sé si existe una forma profesional u oficial de hacerlo, la [especificación](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#console-namespace) no indica que lo haya por lo menos.

La manera que tú lo estás haciendo te obliga a colocar un `if` por cada `console`, una forma de ahorrarte esto es agregar una segunda función (a modo de auxiliar) que guarde la función `console.log`, luego sobrescribimos esta última. Además podemos agregar una propiedad `enable` para habilitar y deshabilitar la consola a discreción

```js
process = {env: {ENABLE_CONSOLE: false}};


console.log2 = console.log;
console.enable = process.env.ENABLE_CONSOLE;
console.log = function(){
  if (console.enable){
     console.log2(...arguments);
  }
}

// TEST
console.log("HOLA 1");
console.enable = true;
console.log("HOLA 2");
console.enable = false;
console.log("HOLA 3");
```

Comment: No creo que necesites habilitar la función en medio de la ejecución. Podría ser una decisión que se haga antes de ejecutar el código. Quizá sea mejor idea crear una clase o un objeto que internamente pudiese usar console.log y se encargue de comprobar una variable antes de mostrar por consola el log.

Comment: @Mateo Un objeto envolvente?? si así, las librerías de 3ros siguen mostrando en consola los mensajes.  Yo he pasado por lo mismo, en un entorno productivo tener una aplicación arrojando mensajes por consola es algo poco útil, además que el mero hecho de escribir en la consola cuando está llena gasta recursos (esto lo comprobé, con un programa en C#). Pero a veces es necesario monitorear una actividad, generalmente a causa de un Bug, por este motivo es bueno tener la posibilidad de activar la consola solo para eso y que te muestre mensajes de esa función y no de todas

Comment: Me parece extraño que las librerías de terceros no permitan configurar eso. Acabo de buscar sobre [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1719) y parece permitirlo.

Comment: @Mateo Pero tienen que implementar ese función